# IdP initiated SSO using Spring SAML

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

Is there any good example available for **IdP initiated SSO (Single Sign On)**  using **Spring SAML** for the starters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Spring SAML quick start guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html#quick-start-testing) has a section for testing of IDP-initialized SSO:

> You can test IDP initialized single sign-on with URL
>   https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=replaceWithUniqueIdentifier,
>   after replacing the service provider identifier with the one
>   configured as entityId in your securityContext.xml. It is possible to
>   provide relayState data sent to your SP with parameter RelayState.

Comment: thanks for the reply.                                  
I tried the example by configuring as mentioned at [Spring SAML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html#quick-start-testing).
And then used the link mentioned by you and replaced the spEntityId with the entityId of my SP.
After login when I click on the button(Continue SAML Single Sign On) then I am getting an error **Reason: Identity Provider ID is null.**
Kindly suggest.

Comment: I observed that the **reqId** was **null** in the URL(https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/hos/AdPage.jsp?returnUrl=/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp&reqid=null) generated on login on IdP.

Comment: This works for me. I replaced the spEntitiyID with the one that I added on the https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/hos/ManageSPMetadata.jsp.